# Connect to SQL in RStudio on Databricks

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, databricks

Can you connect to azure sql server from RStudio on databricks?

I have rJava and RJDBC installed on my cluster and can connect in a databricks notebook, but not in RStudio IDE.

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", "/dbfs/FileStore/jars/DatabricksJDBC42.jar")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, JDBC_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

This fucntions properly in a databricks notebook, but in RStudio on databricks I get an error when calling JDBC

```
Error in JDBC(DRIVER) : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Comment: Where are you specifying `DRIVER`? It's typical to use something like `drv <- RJDBC::JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", "/some/folder/path/mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar")` with the appropriate driver version number and JRE version number substituted in.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've edited the question to include the driver class and path, which still returns the same error